# Django 3 - Making Model's FK Dropdown Display Current User's Data Only

Tags: python, django

I'm creating my first app with Django and still have a lot to learn, but right now I am completely stuck and need some help. I have a model for Customers and Tickets. I have it so different users can save new customers/tickets and only view their data from the dashboard once logged in. However, when creating a new ticket, there is a dropdown option to select customer for the ticket - and the current user is able to see every users customers.

Here is the code, I'll share more code if needed, but I think this covers what I have going on...

**forms.py**

```py
class TicketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['number', 'customer','date_created','work_description','mechanics','status']
```

**views.py**

```py
def createTickets(request):
    form = TicketForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newticket = form.save(commit=False)
            newticket.shopowner = request.user
            newticket.save()
            return redirect('tickets')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'createticket.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):
    def default_number():
        no = Ticket.objects.count()
        return no + 1
    shopowner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, default= default_number)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=1, on_delete= models.SET_DEFAULT, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    work_description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Service Details: ")
    mechanics = models.ForeignKey(Mechanic, default=1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, verbose_name="Mechanic")
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Open Ticket")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tickets"
```

I need the Customer foreignkey to only display customers of the current user (or 'shopowner') - same thing for mechanic and eventually vehicle but I can figure those out once I know how to get the customer input to display the correct data.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to customize your form a bit, in order to modify the queryset for that particular field. We also need to pass a user from the view:

**forms.py**

```py
class TicketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['number', 'customer', 'date_created', 'work_description', 'mechanics', 'status']

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(shopowner=user)
```

**views.py**

```py
def createTickets(request):
    form = TicketForm(user=request.user)
    # ...
```

Exactly how you define the queryset is going to depend on how you've defined the relationship between `Customer` and `Shopowner`, but this should give you the right approach.

Comment: I'm getting a "TicketForm' object has no attribute 'request'" error.. going to play around with this for a while cause from what I've read elsewhere, this seems to be the way to go. Thank you! As soon as I get it I'll mark this as the accepted answer and share what I had to do.

Comment: Ah sorry - was doing this off the top of my head. You'll need to explicitly pass the user to the form. I updated my answer.

Comment: It works!! Thanks Greg, you don't know how much I appreciate it! I suppose I should do a bit more learning on what just happened here so I can understand it better. But, I am happy it works now!